# Rspec Controller Tests not invoking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am new to Rspec and learning about Controller Testing. Now I have the following controller and spec file.

Controller File:

```
class TwzController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :is_authentic?, :only => :angular

    def angular
        @things = current_user.things
        @data_attributes = current_user.data_attributes
    end
```

Spec File:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe TwzController do 
  describe 'GET#Angular' do
    it "renders the angular template" do
      get :angular
      expect(response).to render_template :angular
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the route for this controller#method:

```
get '/dashboard/' => 'twz#angular', :as=>'dashboard'
```

When I run bundle exec rspec all my model tests are run but not this controller test.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's the name of the file?

Comment: How are you running the test?  What happens if you run `bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/twz_controller_spec.rb`?

Comment: Graeme & apneadiving I made a mistake with the naming convention. I didn't append _spec to the test files. Adding _spec made everything work. Thanks!